# Is it possible to use join hint with a cross join in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use join hint with a cross join in T-SQL? If so what is the syntax?

```
select * 
from tableA
cross ? join tableB
```

Comment: Both tables are going to be scanned in full, so I suspect any hint you give would impact performance. Why do you want to give a hint here? I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to fix my execution plan, my estimated rows are very off in the nested loop join. I have changed a cursor to a cross join... The code is faster now with the cross join, but I want to make it even faster. So I just want to experiment with a join hint... The predicates are all function so I think it affects the statistics...

Comment: If the estimates are wrong, I would suggest that the statistics are out of date. Definitely an XY Problem.

Comment: @Larnu I have 900 out af 2000000 as actual and estimated for the nested loop join..And I think it is the step where the cross join is happening...

Comment: @Larnu. But I just created the indexes few days ago... There were no indexes when I created them...

Comment: @Larnu The code only runs once per day. Does it make sense to update the statistics before every execution?

Comment: For specifics for index maintenance, you're better off asking on [dba.se] .

Comment: @Larnu it is a table from ETL so a lot of new data every day  ... Right now with a full table the code takes 90 min if server is not buissy... Maybe update statistics in the begining of the code will be a good tradeoff if it can make it run faster.. But the predicates are getdate() - 30 and complicated string functions...

Comment: The short answer is no, [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#syntax). If you find a `CROSS JOIN` is internally rewritten to use a different kind of join (which can easily happen when conditions are added), and you want to hint that (notwithstanding that join hints are a last resort), rewrite the query yourself to match the execution plan. If that's not an option, you'd have to fumble around with things like forced execution plans, which are no fun. Consider Query Store for that sort of work (QS is a great tool in general, where available).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks I turned on Query Store a couple of days ago and a senior colleague said to turn it off... He thinks it affects performance... I think bad queries affect performance a lot more....

Comment: He is correct; QS *does* affect performance -- but obviously MS has taken that into account and ensured it affects performance as little as possible, giving you knobs to tweak the amount of plans retained and everything. [Background article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/query-store-performance-overhead/). If your colleague has no actual numbers on *how much* perf is affected for that particular DB he has no real leg to stand on, especially if actual queries are already performing badly. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I think the main problem is under indexing and the indexes that exist seem to be random...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments

> I am trying to fix my execution plan, my estimated rows are very off
> in the nested loop join. I have changed a cursor to a cross join...
> The code is faster now with the cross join, but I want to make it even
> faster. So I just want to experiment with a join hint...
>
> I have 900 out af 2000000 as actual and estimated for the nested loop
> join..And I think it is the step where the cross join is happening...
>
> it is a table from ETL so a lot of new data every day ..

I have a few suggestions

- Don't go straight for a cross join. If it's doing a nested loop join because of really bad cardinality estimation, try using a hash join hint instead
- It definitely can help to have statistics up-to-date (research the 'Ascending Key Problem' for info). However, you may want to check if your statistics are set to auto-update and whether they get triggered (e.g., after the ETL, view the properties of the statistics to see when they were last updated etc)
- Try to fix the bad cardinality estimate. One way is to split the bigger tasks into smaller tasks (e.g., into temporary tables).
- On the chance you're using table variables (e.g., DECLARE @temptable TABLE) rather than temporary tables (e.g., CREATE TABLE #TempTable) then stop it. Variables (including table variables) don't have statistics. Older versions often assume 1 row in table variables. SQL Server 2019 (as long as you're in the latest compatibility mode) has some changes to this, but still has some big issues.

When you get it down to the one operation that has the bad cardinality estimate, you can also do things like adding indexes/etc to help with that estimate (remember - you can put indexes and primary keys on temporary tables - they can speed up processing too if the table is accessed multiple times).

Comment: Thanks, but I have the cross join because I removed a cursor and the cursor variable was being used in a join condition.. So I can only combine the tables with cross join and latter when other tables get joined I filter... There are 4 joins (tables) and I filter them latter based on another table.. I will try to make a temp table ..

Comment: Thanks for the tick! Note the temp table thing is to help with cardinality estimates. If you find (for example) the first part of a query gets it really wrong, you can instead save that into a temp table then run the second part of the query using the temp table - which hopefully gets better estimates. However, with this strategy, you really need to focus on keeping the data size as small as possible (e.g., don't cross join 2 million rows and 1 million rows and store within a temp table).

Comment: The 5 tables are too interwined too split up. There are scalar UDF which use columns from different tables in the select.... I can maybe take one table out but I don't think it is worth the effort...

Comment: I will see what I can do... Thanks for the help... I think next query temp table will be usefull...

Comment: Note that scalar functions also have issues - for example, see Brent Ozar's [opinion of them](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/user-defined-scalar-functions-suck-even-when-they-dont-access-data/). You may want to consider re-writing that part.

Comment: I have found something to rewrite I will post another question

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it started with "no", answering the actual question, as it was asked, before getting going above and beyond :)